# website given without *.cs files, just dll and aspx files

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am considering to do a new project in .NET.
It is maintenance of existing project. I do not have much experience with .NET projects, just some.

Client sent me source code (at least he told me that this is source code), however, I do not see any *.cs files there. It has some dll files and ascx files.

For example, default.aspx file has only one code line

```
<%@ Page CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Tere.Web._default" %>
```

Master page contains some view code (and not Code behind code). The first line of master page is the following:

```
<%@ Master CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Tere.Web.Master.SiteMaster" %>
```

This is a bit confusing for me at this point.

And there is a dll called Tere.dll and Tere.Web.dll.
Can you eplain me, please, does this means that client gave me already compiled website without source code? Or maybe he has not sent me the whole project? So, what should I tell him - that this is not the source code as he thinks?

Comment: That's not the source code.

Comment: tell him that this "this is not the source code as he thinks", what is there to tell? :)

Comment: Well you can use reflector to grab source code from dlls; put you probably don't want to go that way. I once have to do it for customer that lost his source code and it was terrible experience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source code would contain (at least) two files for each webpage, for example default.aspx and default.aspx.cs

When this is compiled, all the .aspx.cs files are compiled into a DLL, while the .aspx files remain as they are. This is what you've been given. You'll probably be able to make certain purely-presentational changes with this (the .aspx file contains the HTML), depending on how exactly the pages were designed. If you want to change what the site *does* though, you'll be out of luck - the behaviour is coded up in the .aspx.cs files which you haven't been given.

Comment: By far-and-away the most complete answer, not only confirming the original question but also offering more explanation :)

Comment: I would also think that the owner believes that whatever is on the production server is the needed source code so he just copied everything from there. I bet they have the code somewhere but as it usually the case they do not have any source vesrsioning system and they do not know where the previous devs left the code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes looks like he's just given you the compiled code and not the code behind files that are linked to the actual pages.

Tell him that he's just supplied the files for deployment rather than the actual source.

Comment: Wasn't by me, though perhaps the fact you've simply confirmed his question - it's more of a comment than an answer..

Comment: ...but @Lloyd was the first one to "answer" this rhetoric question.

Comment: @akonsu - think you must have seen an old comment - edited that one a while back :) I stand by my recent one though.

Comment: @Darren In a sense yes but there's on one way to skin a cat sometimes, although I've expanded a little bit to satiate people :)

Answer (score 2):

From your description I suspect you're right: It is not the actual source. The client probably gave you the compiled code that's been deployed to the webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Your client did simply not sent you the source code, but instead the compiled code (dll) and additional files for the website (aspx). The files with the source code are `.vb` or `.cs`, as you know it.

Answer (score 0):

your c# or vb codes are compiled and stored in you dll files and there is no way to decompile them. When I do a project for a customer, I always send the web.config, dll files, .aspx files and all the util files.

Comment: `and there is no way to decompile them` not strictly true

Comment: I know there are some decompilers but they are not 100% perfect. I tried a couple of times, yes it decompiles some of the system but not the entire system

Comment: You will never get 100% because it's a one to many ratio when compiling from a higher level language into a lower level language.